# MySQLSHOW Suppress Warning in Bash Script

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, debugging

I'm working on a simple bash script and one of the things it does is check whether a database already exists before moving on. It's simple enough code, but I'm getting a warning message whenever I try to run the script and I want to suppress that.

Here is the code:

```
if ! mysql -uroot -proot -e "use $NAME"; then
    echo YES
else
    echo NO
fi
```

So, as output, I get the following message when the if statement returns true:

```
ERROR 1049 (42000) at line 1: Unknown database 'database'
YES
```

How can I suppress that message? It doesn't stop the script from running, but I would prefer not to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply tells you that the DB with the name `database` (which is apparently passed as a value of the `$NAME` variable) doesn't exist. Use the correct DB name and there'll be no warning.

To simply mute the warning redirect all the output to `/dev/null` as usual:

```
if ! mysql -uroot -proot -e "use $NAME" 2>&1 >/dev/null; then
    echo YES
else
    echo NO
fi
```

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood my question. I am asking how to "suppress" that warning message. I understand why it appears.